# how to scan characters in a file until newline and store it in a dynamic array?

Tags: c

For example, the program grabs the line: `Hello World!` and assigns the string to a dynamic array.
The length of each line is unknown and I want compatibility for all sizes.

Comment: you can use the POSIX function `getline()`.

Answer (score -1):

`getline()` is the obvious answer here like Barmar suggested, but `fgets()` is also an option (see https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C_Programming/stdio.h/fgets).

But from what I understand, you don't know its size yet you want to put it into a perfectly sized dynamic array right off the bat? That's gonna take some crafty thinking and is difficult with a compiled language. The only way I can think of off the top of my head is quite long in time of execution; open the file twice, once to get each line size, and next time to read in each line of the file with the given file size after `malloc`'ing the correct number of bytes, and storing pointers to these dynamic arrays in a list. This is going to take a lot longer to execute, so if you're not limited on CPU power, this may be an option.

Normally, you'd just know what maximum size to expect and have the array defined at that maximum size. In the grand scheme of things, an extra 50 bytes isn't gonna hurt anything... which hurts me as an embedded guy to say that, but computers have large enough memory these days...

Comment: `getline()` is not a standard function. Without more information in the text, we should stick to the tags which currently only allows for standard library functions.